# Looking for a GTD tool with synchronisation capability

Tags: ipad, icloud, data-synchronization

There are a lot of Getting Things Done (GTD) tools out there I can use to manage my tasks. Additionally, most of them include synchronisation capabilities I can use to synchronize my iPad, MacBook etc. There is only one problem: they all use the Amazon Cloud/a Cloud located not in Europe... But I'm only allowed to use a Cloud that is located in Europe (data privacy aspects etc... this is a constraint of my employer). Does anybody know a GTD tool that is hosted on an "European Cloud" or that can be installed on my private cloud?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OmniFocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus) is able to sync between instances (OS X and iOS)

- locally via Bonjour
- via a shared directory
- via any WebDAV server

Comment: You should definitely use OmniFocus and your own WebDAV server. Highly recommended and they have great Mac and iOS apps.

Comment: I have been using OmniFocus on Mac and iPad with the OmniSync server - works very well and very quick.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Things by Cultured Code](http://culturedcode.com/things/).  It has been fantastic.  It syncs with all my iOS devices.  I believe they are based Germany, so you may be in luck with your cloud requirements.

Comment: I asked, they use globally distributed servers

Comment: Things Cloud Sync runs on Google App Engine, if that helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Appigo's ToDo and ToodleDo both have the GTD structure built into the core. the UX for ToDo is much better than ToodleDo. Price is competitive as well.

Answer (score 0):

6wunderkinder's [Wunderlist](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist) is a great GTD tool with synchronization across all major platforms (web, ios, android, mac, pc). The team itself is based in Berlin, though I'm not sure if that meets your cloud requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out http://www.Gtdagenda.com for an online GTD manager.

You can use it to manage your goals, projects and tasks, set next actions and contexts, use checklists, and a calendar.
Syncs with Evernote, and also comes with mobile-web version, and Android and iPhone apps.

Comment: Given that the asker was looking for a Europe-based cloud solution it would be good to know where you store the data.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Lion or later, the Reminders app that comes with the OS is pretty good and it auto syncs with your iOS devices.